# The next_posts_link() works only with original $wp_query

Tags: posts, wp-query, pages, pagination

I've got custom template that I want to display paged blog posts. This is the beginning of my file:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($wp_query->have_posts()){
        while($wp_query->have_posts()){ $wp_query->the_post();
            //something...
    <?php next_posts_link('Older Entries'); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries'); ?>
```

It works fine - it displays OLDER and NEWER links when it should. On the first page it will display only a link to older entires. On the second page both to newer entries and yet older ones etc.

But I don't want to overwrite current `$wp_query`... I want to use let's say `$wp_query2` for this loop. And the links don't appear at all if I do this.

According to this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link they print a link to the prev/next set of posts within the current query. I assume that `$wp_query2` isn't my "CURRENT QUERY" but `$wp_query` always is. Can I change that somehow?

UPDATE:
Adding `&paged=2` manually to the link causes it to correctly go to the next set of posts (next page) and on second, third etc. page `previous_posts_link()` works even if I use `$wp_query2`. So, I'm just missing `next_posts_link()` functionality on every page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` use the global `$wp_query`.

> ```
> function get_next_posts_link( $label = null, $max_page = 0 ) {
>     global $paged, $wp_query;
> ```
>
> http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1523

That means you need to do something like this to get those to work correctly.

```
$orig_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
// the rest of your code
$wp_query = $orig_query;
```

If you are done with `$wp_query` for that page load there is no reason to preserve it. It should be pretty easy to copy those core functions, modify them to accept a query parameter and create your own paging functions.

Comment: Thanks. Subtler than just overwriting $wp_query. The *_post_link functions only use $wp_query to compute the $max_pages parameter value, so a Stack Overflow discussion recommends simply passing in that value rather than overwriting $wp_query. Which seems simpler in a way, but makes me a little nervous since it assumes future WP versions will act that way (not guaranteed: it's not part of the API/contract, but instead relies on knowledge of the code's inner variable handling). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364488/wordpress-pagination-next-posts-link-on-custom-wp-query-not-showing

Comment: That is a good point but you are putting the variable back so overwriting `$wp_query` shouldn't be a problem. Honestly, I rarely even encounter this problem-- `pre_get_posts` makes it pretty easy to avoid.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I agree, your method is safe. My comment about riskiness referred to the Stack Overflow solution. That other solution looks simpler on the surface (just add a parameter), but it relies on assumptions about the inner workings of WordPress core code... most likely safe, but inner code workings can change. +1 your solution because it seems more future-proof.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the wordpress source, it looks like next_posts_link uses the global var $paged.  My guess is that is only going to work for the primary loop.

A pretty good solution on how to make pagination work for secondary loops is here:
http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/

It involves setting the paged query var explicitly in the query, like this:

```
<h3>Recent Articles</h3>
<ul>
<?php 
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('showposts=5'.'&paged='.$paged);
?>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I have nested loops, so in the inner loop I am using `$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);` instead of the global `WP_Query`. The solution I used was to explicitely pass `max_num_pages` to the `next_posts_link` function. This has been [mentioned in the comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77661/the-next-posts-link-works-only-with-original-wp-query#comment137040_77666) by Andy Giesler as well.

Solution:

```
<?php  
  //outer loop  
    //some outer code
    //inner loop starts
      $inner_query = new WP_Query( 
                array('posts_per_page' => '4', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged')) 
            ); 
        // ...show all posts etc code  
      previous_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); 
      next_posts_link( 'Newer posts', $inner_query->max_num_pages ); //Note this
    //inner loop finishes
    //some other outer loop code  
  //outer loop finishes
?>
```

The reason we have to do this is that [wordpress internally](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.9/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2474-L2503) use global WP_query's `$max_page` property, which if is undefined then the default will be  `$max_page = 0`