# Is that the query_posts() the real criminal here?

Tags: query-posts, previous, next

```
<div class="single_post">
    <?php
    // The Query
    query_posts( $args );
    // The Loop
    if(have_posts()) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="left_date">
        <h1><?php the_time('d') ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_time('M') ?></p>
        <span class="year"><p><?php the_time('Y') ?></p></span>
    </div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
    <div class="author_tag">
        <span class="author">By: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
        <span class="tag"><?php the_tags(); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <div class="read_comment">
            <a href="#" title="Full post"><span class="read">Read more</span></a>
            <a href="#" title="Comment here"><span class="comment">Comment</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="gap"></div>
    <?php
        endwhile;
        endif;
        // Reset Query
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts') ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>') ); ?></div>
</div>
```

The whole code works fine. But the last two line ain't working, I mean the next posts and previous posts button ain't appeared.

```
<div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts') ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>') ); ?></div>
```

Why is this happening? Is it for `query_posts( $args )` function what I used? What should I do now? I just want to show that two paginate link. I believe the solution should be very simple.

Comment: Why `query_posts` not `WP_Query`? Citation from [query_posts Caveats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats): "Before deciding to use query_posts(), be sure to understand the drawbacks.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put them between endwhile; and endif;

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now, they are appeared. But one new problem here, when I click on the "older posts" or "newer posts", it shows the same posts. It's not going to other posts. Could you solve that too? I am going to accept your question.

Comment: Are the navigation shown links different than current post url?

Comment: I think Yes. It's different. It's the main link where current posts are stayed http://localhost/wp/blog/

When I click on the "older posts" button, the url becomes http://localhost/wp/blog/page/2/

But the posts are same as http://localhost/wp/blog/ link.

Comment: what are the `$args` for the query?

Comment: Actually I don't know much about wordpress. When I use query_posts( $args ); ..... wp_reset_query(); the posts appear fine. But If I don't use them, my posts don't show up. So I just use them. I believe there is any kind of conflicting issue between 'query_post' and navigation'next_posts_link' + 'previous_posts'. Could you help me without any major changing in the code? @Michael

Comment: Oh, I got the solution. I changed query_posts( $args ); with

<?php
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts("cat=3&showposts=2&paged=$page");
?>

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77661/next-posts-link-works-only-with-original-wp-query/77666#77666 about the `next_posts_link` issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to add the navigation options after resetting the query, this is needed by the navigation methods to setting accurately those values needed.

Just Move your [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) below your navigation lines.