# how could I get the pagination as I want to when query posts using get_posts function

Tags: query-posts, pagination, get-posts

I am using WP3.5, and I have a `post_list.php` which will show all the posts order by post date DESC. Everything is ok except `pagination`.

I have 15 posts, for test purpose, I want to every page show 2 posts, others will be show next page like this.

```
Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next
```

Some parts of post_list.php

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once '../blog/wp-load.php';

$query_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'offset' => 0

);
$lateset_posts = get_posts($query_args);

<?php 
global $post;
foreach($lateset_posts as $post) :
    // do something
    the_content();
<?php endforeach;?>

<?php next_post_link(); previous_post_link(); ?>
```

Yes, as you see, every page show 2 posts as I set, but I cannot get the pagination as I want to. Instead, it shows me like this

```
Post1's title >> << Post2's title
```

How could I get the pagination style like below

```
Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next
```

Thanks.

Edit:
Now I use `paginate_links` function, yes, I got what I want.

```
$query_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'offset' => 0

);
$lateset_posts = get_posts($query_args);


$paging_args = array(
    'base'         => '%_%',
    'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
    'total'        => count($lateset_posts),
    'current'      => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'end_size'     => 1,
    'mid_size'     => 1,
    'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'    => __('Next »')
);
$lateset_posts_paging = paginate_links($paging_args);
```

I have 15 rows , and it shows like this

```
 1 2 3 .. Next
```

Now I am in the first page, and I want to go to the second page, so I click the number 2, and I notic the url is :

```
http://localhost/x/post_list.php?paged=2
```

But after I click it ,it `still in the first page`, and the data is also the first two rows. Where is am I wrong , Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links). It is meant to do pretty much just that. Plus, the ordinary pagination functions like [`next_posts_link` (which I think you want instead of `next_post_link`) do not work reliably with custom queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77666/21376), but `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` are equally or more troublesome with custom queries.

With [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) you need to pass quite a bit of data, so read the Codex carefully.

Comment: thanks s_ha_dum, indeed, I need to read the Codex carefully. Thanks.

Comment: hi, I edit my question, after I use this funciton, I found I can not go to the page what I want to go.

Comment: Your function is not using the 'paged' parameter that `paginate_links` is sending. By the way, I'd use some other key than `paged` as WordPress uses that and you may end up with conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I need to add a '`paged`' parameter to my `get_posts` function

```
$query_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'offset' => 0,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')

);
```