# pagination for blog landing page

Tags: pagination, blog-page

I have a blog page at: mysite.com/blog. On this page I have this loop:

```
<?php

$args = array (
  'pagination'             => true,
  'paged'                  => 'pages',
  'posts_per_page'         => '5',
  'ignore_sticky_posts'    => true
 );
?>

<?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<?php the_title('<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>'); ?>

<p class="byline">
  <span class="author vcard"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span> <span class="sep">|</span> 
  <abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time(__('l, F jS, Y, g:i a', 'example')); ?>"><?php the_time(__('F j, Y', 'example')); ?></abbr>
  <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'example'), ' <span class="sep">|</span> <span class="edit">', '</span> '); ?>
</p>

<div class="entry-content">
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php wp_link_pages('before=<p class="pages">' . __('Pages:','example') . '&after=</p>'); ?>
</div>

<p class="entry-meta">
  <span class="categories"><?php _e('Posted in', 'example'); ?> <?php the_category(', '); ?></span>
  <?php the_tags('<span class="tags"> <span class="sep">|</span> ' . __('Tagged', 'example') . ' ', ', ', '</span>'); ?> 
  <span class="sep">|</span> <?php comments_popup_link(__('Leave a response', 'example'), __('1 Response', 'example'), __('% Responses', 'example'), 'comments-link', __('Comments closed', 'example')); ?> 
</p>
```

Which works as expected, however I cannot get pagination to work. I have tried a variety of options. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with no 404s

```
 <?php
 $args = array (
    'posts_per_page' => 5 ,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => true
  );
  $blog_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if ( $blog_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { 
     next_posts_link('&larr; Older posts', $blog_query->max_num_pages); 
     previous_posts_link('Newer posts &rarr;', $blog_query->max_num_pages); 
  } 
  while ( $blog_query->have_posts() ) {
      $blog_query->the_post();

     // STUFF
  }
     if ( $blog_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { 
     next_posts_link('&larr; Older posts', $blog_query->max_num_pages); 
     previous_posts_link('Newer posts &rarr;', $blog_query->max_num_pages); 
  }
  wp_reset_query();
  ?>
```

I can see the need for a secondary loop if you want to not use category pages or want there to be editable content on the page or a title different than the category name.

Comment: This alone is almost certainly not going to work because this is a secondary loop and the [ordinary pagination functions do not work well](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77666/21376) with secondary loops, plus the main query will be out of sync with the secondary query so you are likely to get 404s.

Comment: I added some info

Comment: `next_posts_link` [assumes the main query](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1523), so are paginating on a different query than you are using to display the posts. The same is true with `previous_posts_link`. There will be problems because of that.

Comment: I'm specifying the blog query in it

Comment: This seems to be working for me so far.

Comment: Try pasting your code somewhere that is already paging, like `category.php` or `index.php`. I get a 404 on the very first click. Your pagination is out of sync of the main query, even if you get the pagination links to display correctly. See what I mean?

Comment: How would I know if the paging is out of sync? It seems to be fine. I am using http://www.rootstheme.com/ as a starter theme.

Comment: no idea what Roots might be doing but I can tell because I click a link and immediately get a 404.

Comment: s_ha_dum is right about this if it's on a page that is already paging. I can see it in the core.  I tested this in it's own page template.  If it's deployed like that it will work.  I got those errors when I dropped it into category.php

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to create a secondary Loop. Besides causing additional work for the server, the [ordinary pagination functions do not work well with secondary loops](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77666/21376).

Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query.

```
function pregp_wpse_104648($qry) {
  if (is_main_query() && $qry->is_home()) {
    $qry->set('posts_per_page','5');
    $qry->set('ignore_sticky_posts',true);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_104648');
```

I believe that is all you need.

Note: I am guessing at the conditions you need. `if (is_main_query() && $qry->is_home()) {` may be wrong, but that is the idea.

Comment: If I don't create the loop, my posts don't display. All I get is the title of the page (where it should be the title of the post). I am using a custom template (blog.php) and under settings/reading posts page is set to 'blog'.

Comment: You need the Loop, what you don't need is a secondary Loop-- the new query--, unless you are doing something odd with the blog index.

Comment: Sorry -- I think I should have said query. Without the query, it doesn't work.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to use this?

Comment: mysite.com/blog. There is a template page set for the 'blog' page. It is named 'blog.php'. Under settings/reading posts page is set to 'blog'.

Comment: Seems like there should be a query. Try `global $wp_query; var_dump($wp_query->posts);` Do you get a big dump of unformatted post data?

Comment: Only a small dump. It should be all posts, right?

Comment: It should be posts up to the post per page limit set on the backend.

Comment: It is not -- it appears to be what was generated on the front end when I removed the query, and had only the loop. -- http://codepen.io/simply-simpy/pen/cLxje

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9444/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-scott-simpson)