# next_posts_link(); & previous_posts_link(); not working properly

Tags: pagination

I am creating a wordpress theme in which there is a page named "**blog**" which will show my all latest blog posts. Here, i am displaying only 5 posts per page and i want in first page it will only show "**Newer**" link, in second page it will show both "Older" and "Newer" link and also "**Older**" link on last page like [this](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/). Here, m using following code for my task and its not working as expected.

This is the function I am using in **functions.php** to alter custom post type "**blog**". But this is also not working, its showing no posts instead of 5 which i've set here.

```
// ----------------------- Set the number of a custom post type posts per page
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'be_archive_query' );
function be_archive_query( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_post_type_archive('blog') ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
    }
}
```

This is my **page-blog.php**

```
<div class="post-content">

    <?php
    if(have_posts()) {
        while(have_posts()) {
            the_post();
            $link = get_permalink();
            echo "<div id='bl-post'>";

            echo "<div class='thumb'>";
            echo "<a href=$link>";
            if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                }
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class='cont'>";
                echo "<h2 class='bl-post-title'><a href=$link>";
                the_title();
                echo "</a></h2>";
                echo "<p>";
                     $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                     echo string_limit_words($excerpt,30);                                  
                echo "</p>";
                echo "<a href=$link id='cont-read'>";
                _e('Read More','nss-framework');
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</div>";

            echo "</div>";
        }
            ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <ul class="sl-navi">
                    <li>
                        <a data-hover="Previous" href="#">
                            <span><?php next_posts_link(__('Older','nss-framework')); ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-hover="Next" href="#">
                            <span><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer','nss-framework')); ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            <?php
    }

    ?>

</div>
```

This is my **single-blog.html**

```
<div class="clr"></div>


<ul class="sl-navi">
        <li>
            <a data-hover="Previous" href="#">
                <span>Previous</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-hover="Next" href="#">
                <span>Next</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Expected previews**

1st page

[image]

2nd page

[image]

Last page

[image]

But, in wp i am getting ds

[image]

I've also checked html part after using `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` functions and I get this (nothing displaying between span tags)

What changes should I make?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77661/next-posts-link-works-only-with-original-wp-query
 Also note that `next_posts_link` print all the link, including <a> tags, in your code you have nested anchor, that I think is html illegal.

Comment: Two questions, **why?** are you using a single page as a blog page, this is surely not why single pages are meant for, and that is why your asetup won't work. Secondly, why are you running a custom query?

Comment: next_posts_link(); & previous_posts_link(); are also not working on my index page of other themes wch i am developing...

Comment: Those links will never work if you are not using the main query. Drop your custom queries, use the default loop and use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query

Answer (score 1):

I did this and its working as expected. Please close this question

```
<div class="post-content">

    <?php
    // set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5&post_type=blog&paged=' . $paged );
    if($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $link = get_permalink();
            echo "<div id='bl-post'>";

            echo "<div class='thumb'>";
            echo "<a href=$link>";
            if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                }
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class='cont'>";
                echo "<h2 class='bl-post-title'><a href=$link>";
                the_title();
                echo "</a></h2>";
                echo "<p>";
                     $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                     echo string_limit_words($excerpt,30);                                  
                echo "</p>";
                echo "<a href=$link id='cont-read'>";
                _e('Read More','nss-framework');
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</div>";

            echo "</div>";
        }
            ?>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <ul class="sl-navi">
                    <li>
                        <span><?php next_posts_link('Older', $the_query->max_num_pages); ?></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span><?php previous_posts_link('Newer'); ?></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php
    }

    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer so this can show as solved ;-)